# Viewing my objects in the default 3d (iso) view

Tags: 3d-view

I'm brand new to blender so please go easy me! This question is asked a lot yet I can't seem to find the answer. When you start up Blender, the default includes a cube mesh shown in 3 point perspective/ Isometric view. How can I return exactly to that view (same angle, distance, etc) even after I change the object. I know can change the viewpoint to top, right, left, bottom, front and back but there seems to be no viewpoint that returns me to that isometric, 3 point perspective view that I started out with. Viewpoint camera gets me there but when I toggle out of the camera viewpoint back to the last, orthographic view.
Any tips? A shortcut perhaps?
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: did you try moving the default camera to the startup viewing angle using Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0, then saving the startup file that way you can get back to it using the Numpad 0 shortcut. you can then have other camera to render out different angles.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default view Blender starts at. There is nothing special about it, so there naturally is not hotkey. However, you can restore this view by assuming its position by rotating the interface.

I am unsure from your question whether or not you are actually able to rotate the viewport. If you cannot, simply hold down the middle mouse button on your mouse and move around. If you do not have a middle mouse button/ are using a touchpad, then you can go to user preferences, and enable "Emulate three button mouse". This allows you to rotate the viewport by holding the left mouse button, and pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on your keyboard.

If you, however, can rotate the interface and I am mistaken, you can, immediately after opening Blender, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> on your keyboard to align the camera to that default view. Make sure you have not already moved the interface around.

As I said previously, there is no "default" key to this view, so you must align your camera to the view if you want to get it again. If you don't want to do this, you can try to achieve the same view by rotating your viewport.

I hope this helps.